# GET all stopped/started services, difference between microsoft and non microsoft services and then to save microsoft/non microsoft, started/stopped

Tags: powershell

like in the title, I would like to do in POWERSHELL the following:
GET all stopped/started services, difference between microsoft and non microsoft services and then to save microsoft/non microsoft, started/stopped in separate files, could you please help me? I'm a total beginner in this,

Thanks a lot and have a nice day!

I only know how to get

```
Get-WmiObject win32_service | where { $_.Caption -match "Windows" -and $_.PathName -match "Windows" -and $_.state -match 'stopped' } | Sort-Object -Property @{Expression = "Name"; Descending = $true} | Out-File "microsoftservicesstopped $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm).txt"
```

microsoft/non microsoft ones and save to file but to take also started and stopped and combine them in a pipeline for in the end to save them all 4 types separately is beyond my knowledge.

Thank you so much for your help and time!

Comment: Use Like instead of Match.  The caption names contain "windows". Here is an example "Windows Management Instrumentation".  First true without the Where :  Get-WmiObject win32_service | foreach {Write-host "caption = " $_.Caption ",Path = " $_.Path}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Get all services and filter them by whether they are running or 
stopped
$services = Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq 'Stopped' -or 
$_.Status -eq 'Running'}

# Filter the services by whether they are Microsoft services or not
$MicrosoftServices = $services | Where-Object {$_.Name -like 'M*' - 
or $_.Name -like 'W*'}
$NonMicrosoftServices = $services | Where-Object {($_.Name -notlike 
'M*' -and $_.Name -notlike 'W*')}

# Save the Microsoft services to a file
$MicrosoftServices | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq 'Running'} | Out- 
File C:\Temp\MicrosoftServicesStarted.txt
$MicrosoftServices | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq 'Stopped'} | Out- 
File C:\Temp\MicrosoftServicesStopped.txt

# Save the non-Microsoft services to a file
$NonMicrosoftServices | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq 'Running'} | 
Out-File C:\Temp\NonMicrosoftServicesStarted.txt
$NonMicrosoftServices | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq 'Stopped'} | 
Out-File C:\Temp\NonMicrosoftServicesStopped.txt
```

Comment: format your answer.